# Dynamic MongoDB queries

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs

I'm pretty new to NoSQL databases and I'm trying to figure out how to programmatically build MongoDB API queries. I'm using Angular 2 for my frontend and Node.js for my backend.

I have users filtering songs and I want them to be able to filter them by multiple genres, I have 9 different genres.

My base query is:

```
{"order": "created DESC"}
```

Then, for example - If they select hipHop and pop I want to make a function that will build this query. They can only add genres, so it would just be a matter of adding more or less genres inside the and brackets.

```
{"where": {
     "and": [
          {"genres.house": {"exists": "true"}},
          {"genres.pop": {"exists": "true"}}
     ]
   },
   "order": "created DESC"
}
```

I'm using mLab for the DB and loopback to build my API. Not sure if that matters.

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry but what is the question?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I want to know how I would write a function that would  add onto my base query (the first one) and given an array of genres, create something like the second query. The only thing that would change in the function would be the number of genres. I updated the question a little. Does that make sense? Otherwise I'll update my question again and be more clear.

Comment: You pretty much nailed it already from what I can tell. Just pass the selected genres to your node backend where you have some adding together so you get a long $and clause. Check out mongooseJS if you haven't already. It's a wrapper for MongoDB. It is pretty good documented :)